# Split by regex of new line and capital letter

Tags: python, regex

I've been struggling to split my string by a regex expression in Python.

I have a text file which I load that is in the format of:

```
"Peter went to the gym; \nhe worked out for two hours \nKyle ate lunch 
 at Kate's house. Kyle went home at 9. \nSome other sentence 
 here\n\u2022Here's a bulleted line"
```

I'd like to get the following output:

```
['Peter went to the gym; he worked out for two hours','Kyle ate lunch 
at Kate's house. He went home at 9.', 'Some other sentence here', 
'\u2022Here's a bulleted line']
```

I'm looking to split my string by a new line and a capital letter or a bullet point in Python.

I've tried tackling the first half of the problem, splitting my string by just a new line and capital letter.

Here's what I have so far:

```
print re.findall(r'\n[A-Z][a-z]+',str,re.M)
```

This just gives me:

```
[u'\nKyle', u'\nSome']
```

which is just the first word. I've tried variations of that regex expression but I don't know how to get the rest of the line.

I assume that to also split by the bullet point, I would just include an OR regex expression that is in the same format as the regex of splitting by a capital letter. Is this the best way?

I hope this makes sense and I'm sorry if my question is in anyway unclear. :)

Comment: You could also use str.splitlines() which is a built-in function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `split` function:

```
>>> str = u"Peter went to the gym; \nhe worked out for two hours \nKyle ate lunch at Kate's house. Kyle went home at 9. \nSome other sentence here\n\u2022Here's a bulleted line"
>>> print re.split(u'\n(?=\u2022|[A-Z])', str)
```

```
[u'Peter went to the gym; \nhe worked out for two hours ',
 u"Kyle ate lunch at Kate's house. Kyle went home at 9. ",
 u'Some other sentence here',
 u"\u2022Here's a bulleted line"]
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/9otmsC)

Answer (score 1):

You can split at a `\n` proceeded by a capital letter or the bullet character:

```
import re
s = """
Peter went to the gym; \nhe worked out for two hours \nKyle ate lunch 
at Kate's house. Kyle went home at 9. \nSome other sentence 
here\n\u2022Here's a bulleted line
"""
new_list = filter(None, re.split('\n(?=•)|\n(?=[A-Z])', s))
```

Output:

```
['Peter went to the gym; \nhe worked out for two hours ', "Kyle ate lunch \nat Kate's house. Kyle went home at 9. ", 'Some other sentence \nhere', "•Here's a bulleted line\n"]
```

Or, without using the symbol for the bullet character:

```
new_list = filter(None, re.split('\n(?=\u2022)|\n(?=[A-Z])', s))
```

Comment: Or `\n(?=[A-Z]|•)` and `\s*\n(?=[A-Z]|•)`

Comment: Hey - thank you both for the super helpful comments. Your snippet works perfectly for the capital letter. However, it's unable to detect the bullet character. Here's the output I get: `[u'Peter went to the gym; he worked out for two hours ', u"Kyle ate lunch \nat Kate's house. Kyle went home at 9. ", u"Some other sentence here\n\u2022Here's a bulleted line"]`